# Execute x86 PDFCreator.exe in the "Program Files (x86)" folder from x64 the command line w arguments?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, 64-bit

How can I call an x86 application in the `Program Files (x86)` folder from the x64 command prompt?  The x86 exe functions w/o problems on a x64 Win XP, but how to call it from a command propmt?

```
>> C:\Program Files (x86)\theExe.exe
```

or

```
>> cd C:\Program Files (x86)\
>> theExe.exe
```

or

```
>> start "C:\Program Files (x86)\theExe.exe"
```

Neither of the above worked ...

==== 
Edit : I changed the title, and will state basically an extended question:

It turns out that the problem goes a little further ... If I have to start PDFCreator.exe like the answer below, and like suggested on their web site, It should go like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\pdfcreator.exe /IF\"C:\description.ps\" /OF\"C:\description.pdf\""
```

(considering treating quotation marks as literals, i.e. using the escape character '\'). However, it will refuse to start, stating no such command... Any idea?

Comment: Windows' command line escape character is `^`, not `\ `. That may help.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to enclose the line in quotes:

```
>> "C:\Program Files (x86)\theExe.exe"
```

Window cmd uses space to delimit commands and parameters and so enclosing with quotes tells the parser to ignore any spaces between the quote marks, and accept the entire thing as a command.

Comment: Thanks, Im giving you the point (If I could, dont have enough reputation). However, it turns out that the problem goes a little further ... If I have to start this one: "C:\Program Files (x86)\pdfcreator.exe /IF\"C:\description.ps\" /OF\"C:\description.pdf\"", it refuses to start it. Any idea ?

Comment: @HeinrichStack as the other answer states (and my own), the quotes should enclose the executable and its path, not the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Close the quotes at end of `pdfcreator.exe` and replace `\"` with `"`

Try running as mentioned below:-

```
>> "C:\Program Files (x86)\pdfcreator.exe" /IF"C:\description.ps" /OF"C:\description.tif"
```

Comment: Thanks, but that wont worked. I had already tried this.

Comment: @HeinrichStack: Whats the error message you are getting?